# Magento 2 - Remove Currency Switcher

Tags: magento2, header, multicurrency

I'm trying to remove the currency switcher from the header in Magento 2 with little luck. I've tried this in my theme's default.xml file

```
<referenceBlock name="store.settings.currency" remove="true"/>
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. Plan B is to hide it with CSS but I feel like I should be able to remove it with a layout update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Block name to remove currency should be "currency", please try:

```
<referenceBlock name="currency" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove currency from the website totally - do not forget about the mobile version, as there is another template which is responsible for rendering it inside "hamburger". So use both variants (from the question too)

```
<referenceBlock name="currency" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="store.settings.currency" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Go to the following path

**app/design/frontend/Themes/Yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

And add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
   <body>    
       <referenceBlock name="currency" remove="true" />
       <referenceBlock name="store.settings.currency" remove="true" />
   </body>    
</page>
```

**Note:** In case you already have file named “default.xml”, you just need to add the below two lines before the closing of `</body>` tag.